# How can I force Kendo Grid to use a numeric filter on a column

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using the following code, Kendo Grid uses the string filter interface for `t.Files.Count` even though the type is an `int`. How can I force the grid to use the numeric filter UI instead?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GJW_Site.Web.Models.TargetsModel>()    
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(t => t.ID).Width(80);
        columns.Bound(t => t.OrbitalPeriod);
        columns.Bound(t => t.Files.Count);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Targets_Read", "Targets"))
    )
    .Resizable(o => o.Columns(true))
    .ColumnMenu()
)
```

Produces a filter menu for strings:

[image: Filter menu]

I am using Kendo.MVC 2013.1.514.340

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to specify that the value is an `int` in the model - change the `DataSource` method as so:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Targets_Read", "Targets"))
    .Model(m => {
        m.Field<int>(t => t.Files.Count);
    })
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this solution:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Targets_Read", "Targets"))
    .Model(m => {
        m.Field("Files.Count", typeof(System.Int32));
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue when the filter are coming for data type string while my data type is "number", this happens if there is a discrepancy in declaring the schema, make sure the field declared in schema are correct i.e. have same name as the data you are getting/supplying to grid.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo will be able to select a right filter type for each column, but you have to use *properties* instead of *fields* in `TargetsModel`.

For example, use this:

```
public class TargetsModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OrbitalPeriod { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

instead of this:

```
public class TargetsModel
{
    public int ID;
    public string OrbitalPeriod;
    ...
}
```

If for some reason you are unable to do this, the `.Model()` approach is probably the best way.