# How to exclude MVC Kendo Grid's column filter "contains" option?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid, filtering

I'm working on the bug where one screen has a grid that contains a column showing numbers, but when I try to filter it, it has "contains" option.

When I type 0, I'm getting an error.

I need to filter that column as a number not as a string.

This is the fragment of the code:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.DebitAmount).Title("Debit").Width(300).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(DebitAmount,'c') #").ClientFooterTemplate("#=kendo.toString(sum,'c') #");
columns.Bound(x => x.CreditAmount).Title("Credit").Width(300).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(CreditAmount,'c') #").ClientFooterTemplate("#=kendo.toString(sum,'c') #");
```

..................

```
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)
       .Extra(false)
       .Operators(operators => operators
       .ForString(str => str.Clear()
       .Contains("Contains")
       .IsEqualTo("EqualTo")
       .IsNotEqualTo("NotEqualTo")
       .IsEmpty("Empty")))
       .Operators(operators => operators
       .ForNumber(str => str.Clear()
      .IsEqualTo("EqualTo")
      .IsGreaterThan("GreaterThan")
      .IsLessThan("LessThan")
       )).Messages(m => m.IsFalse(" False "))
    .Messages(m => m.IsTrue("True ")))
```

The model declares those fields as decimal

This is the generated part of the screen:

[image]

Another screen has another filterable grid with an Amount field. All the options are declared the same way, but that screen's filter for the Amount field does not include "contains" option when displayed.

This is the code:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Amount).Title("Amount").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(Amount,'c')#").Width("120px");
```

......................

```
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(operators => operators
    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
    .Contains("Contains")
    .IsEqualTo("EqualTo")
    .IsNotEqualTo("NotEqualTo")
    .IsEmpty("Empty")))
    .Operators(operators => operators
    .ForNumber(str => str.Clear()
   .IsEqualTo("EqualTo")
   .IsGreaterThan("GreaterThan")
   .IsLessThan("LessThan")
    )))
```

This is the part of the screen:

[image]

Everything seems the same (except of messages part) when defining the filter operations, but somehow, on the first screen, the "contains" operation is included and on the second is not.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to set the field as a number to filter by number

Comment: Thank you, Keith, for the response. The field is set as decimal in the model and the `ClientTemplate` logic is the same as it is in the working page

Comment: well looking at your code at the top, you have both fields set as  string, so that is what it searches for since its rendered as string

Comment: Looking at different kendo formatting examples here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting, my approach seems to be fine, considering that exactly the same approach works on another grid

Comment: can you show me a grid where its rendered as string but searched by decimal?

Comment: Sure, I'm going to update my question

Comment: Actually, the pieces of codes defining those fields are already in the question

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution here: [How can I force Kendo Grid to use a numeric filter on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574443/how-can-i-force-kendo-grid-to-use-a-numeric-filter-on-a-column?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I had to add the following conversion logic when defining the data source:

```
.Model(c => { c.Field<decimal>(d => d.DebitAmount); })
.Model(c => { c.Field<decimal>(d => d.CreditAmount); })
.Model(c => { c.Field<DateTime>(d => d.RequestedDate); })
```